# python grep reverse matching

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I would like to build a small python script that basicaly does the reverse of grep.
I want to match the files in a directory/subdirectory that doesn't have a "searched_string".

So far i've done that:

```
import os

filefilter = ['java','.jsp'] 
path= "/home/patate/code/project"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name[-4:] in filefilter :
        print os.path.join(path, name)
```

This small script will be listing everyfiles with "java" or "jsp" extension inside each subdirectory, and will output them full path.

I'm now wondering how to do the rest, for example i would like to be able if I forgot a session management entry in one file (allowing anyone a direct file access), to search for :
"if (!user.hasPermission" and list the file which does not contain this string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at the -l, -L, and -v options of grep. -v inverts the match (i.e. prints lines not matching the pattern). -l lists files containing a line that matches the pattern, and -L lists files not containing the pattern.

Comment: Look at os.path.splitext for handling file extension. (http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a file with a path bound to variable `f` contains a string bound to name `s`, simplest (and acceptable for most reasonably-sized files) is something like

```
with open(f) as fp:
    if s in fp.read():
        print '%s has the string' % f
    else:
        print '%s doesn't have the string' % f
```

In your `os.walk` loop, you have the root path and filename separately, so

```
f = os.path.join(path, name)
```

(what you're unconditionally printing) is the path you want to open and check.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your explaination !

Unfortunatly i have some issue to run this :
test.py:22: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

I then run it with python2.6, and get another error:


  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>

    if s in f.read():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the typo, fixed (tx @johnsy).  @thomy, I'm using `print` instead of `return`, of course you can edit that to perform exactly the actions you want instead, in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing file name call function that will check if file content do not match texts you want to have in source files. In such cases I use `check_file()` that looks like this:

```
WARNING_RX = (
    (re.compile(r'if\s+\(!\s+user.hasPermission'), 'user.hasPermission'),
    (re.compile(r'other regexp you want to have'), 'very important'),
    )

def check_file(fn):
    f = open(fn, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    for rx, rx_desc in WARNING_RX:
        if not rx.search(content):
            print('%s: not found: %s' % (fn, rx_desc))
```