# python processs complete list files matched

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to get simple code working, unfortunately I'm a python beginner.

My script should return a list of files that doesn't match a pattern, more information here :
[python grep reverse matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910106/python-grep-reverse-matching/2910288#2910288)

My code is running but doesn't process the complete list of files found as it should :

```
import sys,os

filefilter = ['.xml','java','.jsp','lass']

path= "/home/patate/code/project"

s = "helloworld"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):

   for name in files:

      if name[-4:] in filefilter :

         f = str(os.path.join(path, name))

         with open(f) as fp:

             if s in fp.read():

                print "%s has the string" % f

             else:

                print "%s doesn't have the string" % f
```

This code returns :

> /home/patate/code/project/blabla/blabla/build.xml doesn't have the string
>
> None

If I change `f = str(os.path.join(path, name)) for print str(os.path.join(path, name))`
I can see the whole list being printed.

How can I process the whole list as I wish to ?

Comment: Please format the code correctly - either indent the entire block of code by 4 spaces, or highlight it and click the "101010" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `os.path.splitext` to check for a matching file extension.

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if os.path.splitext(name)[1] in filefilter:
            f = str(os.path.join(path, name))
            with open(f) as fp:
                if s in fp.read():
                    print "%s has the string" % f
                else:
                    print "%s doesn't have the string" % f
```

The rest looks fine.